# How to lock keyboard layout on login screen in Gnome

Tags: login, opensuse, gnome3, keyboard-layout

I use Gnome 3.xx desktop manager on openSUSE 42.xx and two keyboard layouts. I would like to lock the keyboard layout on the Gnome login screen, so it is always US layout. Basically, I want logins and passwords to be only entered in English_US. Is there a way to achieve it?

Or, alternatively, warn the user about non-English layout and caps lock pressed.

I would also appreciate if you could point me to good information sources about tweaks that make experience of working with several keyboard layouts better.